# Does the integral $\int\sqrt{2-\sin(2x)}dx$ have an analytic solution?

Tags: calculus

Trying to find the length of a curve, I have come across this integral:**$$\int\sqrt{2-\sin(2x)}dx$$** Can I resolve it analycally?

Comment: [No, it doesn't look likely](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(2-sin(2x)))

Comment: Have you tried to solve it analyatically? If so, post what you have tried.

Comment: I couldn´t develop anything about it.

Comment: Was the curve an ellipse, by chance?

Comment: I dont remember. I just remember this integral that I couldnt solve analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be expressed using special functions. After substituting $u=x-\dfrac\pi 4$ one obtains an [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

**Edit:**
The motivation for the substitution is the identity
$$1-\sin 2x = 2\sin^2\left( x-\frac\pi 4\right)$$
The incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind is defined as follows:
$$\operatorname{E}(x \mid a^2)=\int_0^x\sqrt{1-a^2\sin^2\theta} \,\mathrm d\theta$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus we thus also have
$$\int \sqrt{1-a^2\sin^2\theta}\,\mathrm d \theta = \operatorname E (x\mid a^2) +\mathrm C$$
from which follows that our integral equals $\operatorname E (u\mid -2)+\mathrm C$ or $\operatorname E \left(x-\dfrac\pi 4\,\middle\vert\, - 2\right) +\mathrm C$.

Comment: Could you develop it better?

Comment: I expanded my answer.